# Buenas! Recién estoy empezando con proyectos de Javascript, y necesitaría algún ejemplo sobre este enunciado

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

Se deberá agregar un botón para borrar por completo los usuarios almacenados en localStorage, pero antes de hacer borrado se deberá generar un código aleatorio de números (10 dígitos random) que la persona deberá tipear en algún input, o prompt para que al comparar el código generado con el ingresado y en el caso de coincidir se deberá borrar el localStorage con el método remove item, de caso contrario no se deberá realizar la acción y se deberá mostrar un swal o alert que indique a la persona que no se efectuo dicho borrado.

Comment: Saludos, bienvenido/a a SOes, aquí tienes lecturas altamente recomendadas: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 + https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour + https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask + https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript (en este link se encuentra la gran documentación de JS de Mozilla). http://tutorialesprogramacionya.com/javascriptya/ + https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/index.htm

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo que mejores tu redacción para tener más posibilidades de obtener una respuesta. Aún así, creo que lo que quieres hacer es:

```js
// Supongamos que tenemos algunos datos en LocalStorage
// localStorage.setItem('saludo', 'Hola Mundo')

function generateKey() {
  const key = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    key[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  } // Genera una lista de 10 números aleatorios del 0 al 9, redondeados para abajo con Math.floor()
  return key;
}

document.querySelector('form').onsubmit = () => { // Estará mirando si el formulario se envía
  const key = generateKey(); // Genera una llave aleatoria
  const inputValue = document.querySelector("input[type='number']").value // Obtiene el valor del input
  if (key === Number(inputValue)) {
    //localStorage.removeItem('saludo', 'Hola Mundo');
    const h2 = document.createElement('h2');
    h2.innerHTML = 'Código validado';
    document.body.appendChild(h2); // Genera una cabecera de segundo nivel que dice "Código validado"
  } else {
    alert('No se efectuó el borrado')
  }
  return false; // Previene que la página se recargue al enviar el formulario, también se podría usar e.preventDefault (e es el primer parámetro opcional de la función) para conseguir lo mismo, estos es obligatorio en React
}
```

```css
/* Para que se vea mejor */
input {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
}
input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  border: 0;
  padding: 1vw;
  margin-top: 1vw;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input type="number" required>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Un par de aclaraciones:

- En la línea 15 del JavaScript también podríamos comparar con "==" y ahorrarnos la conversión a número del valor de nuestro input (que siempre será un string)
- La razón por las que las líneas de localStorage están comentadas es porque Stack Overflow me da un error de seguridad al usarlo :(
- Lamentablemente HTML no nos deja poner un mínimo número de caracteres para elementos , si tuvieramos eso podríamos evitar usos necesarios del JS

Recuerda que en un entorno real para hacer este tipo de validaciones se suele hacer en un servidor con Node.js (en JavaScript) u otro lenguaje de programación como Python, Ruby o PHP.

Comment: Ayudanos a mantener la calidad de la información en el sitio, respondiendo a preguntas realizadas de acuerdo a [ask], si no estás seguro que requiere el OP puedes comentar, saludos.